# How to send variable to view in Grocery Crud?

Tags: codeigniter-3, grocery-crud

I am using Grocery Crud for my web application, I want to send some data from user model to the view, however, since grocery uses $output variable which is initialized as `$output = $crud->render();` and always send it to the view; therefore, I cannot send other data to the view.

Here is my code in controller and what I tried but it does not success.

```
    <?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

            class User1 extends CI_Controller {

                public function __construct()
                {
                    parent::__construct();
                    $this->load->library('grocery_CRUD');
                    $this->load->model('M_User');
                }

                public function index()
                {
                    $this->user();
                }

                public function user($id)
                {
                    // get user information
                    $user = $this->M_User->get_user_info($id);

                  // array variable that I want to send to view a long with variable $output
                    $u = array(
                        'owner_name'=>$user->owner_name,
                        'owner_phone'=>$user->owner_phone,
                        'owner_email'=>$user->owner_email,
                        'owner_facebook'=>$user->owner_facebook,
                        'owner_picture'=>$user->owner_picture,
                        'owner_gender'=>$user->owner_gender
                        );

            // Start Grocery Crud
            $crud = new grocery_CRUD();

            $crud->set_table('room');
            $crud->set_subject('subject');

            $crud->where('owner_id',$id);
            $output = $crud->render();



            // $output = array_merge($output,$u); This is what I tried to do but it did not work.

            $this->load->view('user1',$output);

}
}
?>
```

Is there any way that I could send my variable `$u` to view along with variable `$output` ?

Please kindly advise,
Thanks and Best Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Controller

```
//...
//do all your Grocery Crud staff
//...
$output = $crud->render();

//rending extra value to $output
$data['variable1']='variable_value';
$data['variable2']=12;

$output->data = $data;

$this->load->view('...your page...',$output);
```

> View

```
echo $data['variable1'];
echo $data['variable2'];
```

Answer (score 0):

send data as a parameter to render function 
try this

```
$output = $crud->render($u);
```